# cx_freeze ignores custom variables module

Tags: matplotlib, python-3.3, cx-freeze

I'm trying to freeze a small GUI I made using PyQT5, Matplolib and Python 3.3. 
I'm a beginner so please pardon my ignorance.

The program has:
- one QMainWindow
- two auxiliary QDialogs with Matplotlib plots
- one Variables_Module that I use to store variables (rather than using global)
- one custom Class called ROI

When running from Python terminal the code works fine.

**Issue:** When running the exe obtained with cx_freeze QMainWindow is loaded, user chooses data and data is immediately shown in first QDialog. Second QDialog uses variables stored in the "Variables_Module" and should show a matplotlib hist2d but nothing appears.

For this reason I think Variables_Modules does not get included in the build somehow.

the Main.py has these includes:

```
import sys, time

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, pyqtSignal, QObject
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QMainWindow, QFormLayout, QVBoxLayout,QFileDialog, QDialog, QPushButton, QGridLayout, QMessageBox, QSlider, QSpinBox, QGroupBox, QLabel, QCheckBox, QComboBox, QColorDialog, QProgressDialog
from HySP_main_GUI import Ui_Main
import numpy
from matplotlib.pylab import *
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QTAgg as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot

#these are the "custom" modules
import Variables_Module
from ROI import Resizable_animated_rect
from scipy import ndimage
```

I tried including the "custom" modules in the setup.py in every combination as `Includes` or `includefiles` or `packages` with no solution.

I do understand I'm not supposed to put these modules everywhere but I'm out of ideas.

Also, all files (Main.py, ROI.py, Variables_Module.py) are in the same folder and no errors are given when running `cx_freeze build`.

The setup.py I'm using is:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable


includes = ["ROI","Variables_Module"]
includefiles = ['ROI.py','Variables_Module.py']
excludes = [ 'Tkinter']
packages = ["ROI","Variables_Module"]
path = []

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {
                     "includes":      includes, 
                     "include_files": includefiles,
                     "excludes":      excludes, 
                     "packages":      packages, 
                     "path":          path
}

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
# console application).
base = None
exe = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    exe = Executable(
      script="E:\\Python\\Projects\\test\\test.py",
      initScript = None,
      base="Win32GUI",
      compress = True,
      copyDependentFiles = True,
      appendScriptToExe = False,
      appendScriptToLibrary = False,
      icon = None
    )

setup(  
      name = "test",
      version = "0.1",
      author = 'test',
      description = "My GUI!",
      options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
      executables = [exe]
)
```

Comment: If you run the exe from a command prompt, do you see any errors or warnings?

Comment: No, I tried running the exe from command prompt and weirdly no errors or warnings are given. When I run the py script instead I do get a couple of warnings regarding NaN rounding issues but the code works fine from script.

Comment: Can you show the output from the freezing process? It's probably quite long, so stick it in a pastebin.

Comment: sorry here is the log http://pastebin.com/5UDN4rG7

Comment: finding out I had an <code> from scipy import ndimage</code> nested in one of the classes that I did not report in the main post. I updated now with this import both the post and the log pastebin.
That does not change the result though..

Comment: `Variables_Module` seems to being found just fine. It's possible scipy is the issue - quite a few people have reported issues with frozen applications using scipy.

Comment: the function using scipy however is not called until a button is pressed. What I mean is the initial plot just makes use of matplotlib hist2d function.

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that warnings halt the frozen exe.
Before plotting my new image some warnings regarding NaN were shown and apparently were preventing the app from going on with calculations.

I solved suppressing the warning in the troublesome function using:

```
import warnings

warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
```

this solves the problem. Took 2 days. -_-'

Comment: Yes, Python on Windows has problems if things try to write to the console when the application doesn't have a console - it fills up a buffer and then blocks. It's not specific to warnings; anything that tries to write to stdout/stderr can cause it. The usual workaround [looks like this](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2012-November/msg04489.html).